# toExpontial is undefined in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Always having this **error: num.toExponential is not a funtion. num.toExponential is undefined.**
Why is `toExponential()` doesn't run on react native? How to replicate this functionality in react native?

```
function ifLessOneSatoshi(raw_num){
  const num = raw_num;
  if(raw_num < 0){
    num = Math.abs(raw_num);
  }
  if(num < 0.000001){
    if(raw_num < 0){
      const abn = abs(num);
      return -1 * abn.toExponential();
    }
    return num.toExponential();
  }
  return raw_num;
}
```

**Below is what I implemented based on the answer of Yunhai:**

```
function ifLessOneMillionth(raw_num){
  var num = Number.parseFloat(raw_num); //<=this line you may use parseFloat(raw_num)
  if(raw_num < 0){
    num = Math.abs(raw_num);
  }
  if(num < 0.000001){
    if(raw_num < 0){
      //const abn = Math.abs(num);
      return -num.toExponential(); // this line
    }
    return num.toExponential();
  }
  return raw_num;
}
```

Comment: That block of code you provide is valid and definitely runnable. The problem might come from some where else. I doubt that the num used in your code is not a `num ojbect` so it raises the error.

Comment: When you hover a function, it gives a description, right?This one doesn't. It's just "any" when I hover.

Comment: yes, this would happen if `num` is not a number. Have you ever tried your question sample code. without any block but it still raise the error.

Comment: I edited the code. This is the one I used.

Comment: So if `num` is a string, it will throw an error?

Comment: Yes, but in your case there are other problems you have. See my answer

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to add Math for abs(num). I change this, now it says num is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are fewer problems your have.

First, your reassign `const num`, `const` mean you cannot reaasign variable after declaration. So you should change it to `var` .

Second, the reason of undefined comes from `raw_num` if it isn't a "number object". Depending on the format, you might want to have something like `parseFloat(raw_num)` (I am not sure if the raw_num might be decimal or something else). You need to be careful of that.

Then, the last problem is `-1 * num.toExponential()`，num.toExponential() returns a `string`, so in order to make it negative, you should use `string concatenation` instead of math operation.

```
function ifLessOneSatoshi(raw_num){
  var num = raw_num; //<=this line you may use parseFloat(raw_num)
  if(raw_num < 0){
    num = Math.abs(raw_num);
  }
  if(num < 0.000001){
    if(raw_num < 0){
      const abn = Math.abs(num);
      return -abn.toExponential(); // this line
    }
    return num.toExponential();
  }
  return raw_num;
}
```

There are some weird behavior when I check your code, you have to check out those conditions `if(raw_num)` and `if(num)` by yourself without knowing the intention logic.

Comment: This works well. I ended up using parseFloat as you noted, and also to be generic. I deleted `const abn = Math.abs(num);` ,not necessary anymore since I will not be multiplying `num` anymore. Also concatenation operator for "-" is not necessary, I just prepend it directly like this `-num.toExponential()`.  Thanks!

Comment: I added my final implementation above.

Comment: @user10971804 thx for the string concat noting. glad it helps, do you mind mask the answer as accept.